# sqlite SELECT query error

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I'm trying to execute a query, but I can not understand the problem.
`liste_id_ch`: represents an array of values.

```
      tx.executeSql("SELECT Distinct(IdGroupe)  from Champs where IdChamp IN '"+liste_id_ch+"' ", [], succes_recup_etap, erreur_recup_li

ste_id_grp);
```

Comment: you forgot to describe the problem..

Answer (score 0):

```
String query = "";
for(int i=0;i<liste_id_ch.length();i++)
{
    if(i == liste_id_ch.length() - 1)
      query = query + liste_id.ch(i);
    else
      query = query + liste_id_ch(i) +",";
}

if(query.length() > 0)
{
    tx.executeSql("SELECT Distinct(IdGroupe)  from Champs where IdChamp IN ("+query+")", [], succes_recup_etap, erreur_recup_liste_id_grp);
}
```